# How to find assets of installed pip package

Tags: python, pip

While deploying my application, I need to install a library which contains some assets that must be served from an static directory. That means, during the deploy, I must do the following:

1. `pip install` the package
2. Find the *absolute* location where the package has been installed (this is usually `site-packages` in the virtualenv or global location)
3. Copy the assets from the installed package to the static directory

Is there a portable way of doing step 2? The only starting piece of data that I have to find the installed package is `pip` / `python`.

Is there a way to tell `python`: in what absolute location have you installed a certain package?

Answer (score 1):

If you install package `abc`, you should be able to import that package and get its base location in a python program with:

```
import abc
import os
print(os.path.dirname(abc.__file__))
```

if importing is not possible because of some side-effect this might have you 
can walk `sys.path` and look for `abc.py` or `abc/__init__.py`.

If you have multiple installations, you might not find the version you just installed, but in that case you also would not be running that when importing `abc`, but an older version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding your installed package via the following command.

```
pip show installed-package-name
```

This will return a bunch of attributes with package location. See below example.

```
C:\> pip show selenium
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: selenium
Version: 3.0.0b2
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: d:\appl\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Answer (score 0):

See [pkgutil.get_data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data). File-system based approaches break with packages that are installed as zip-file.

Comment: Zipfiles would also need a completely different approach for adding the assets.